# Is there an online resource for fusion outcomes of various elements at various energy levels?

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, fusion, elements, isotopes

I'm looking to find a chart of nuclides, their potential fusion products and measured energy levels, in a similar vein as [NuDat 3](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat3/), but for fusion.

It doesn't need to be cleanly formatted like NuDat, but a robust list of fusion outcomes would be incredibly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would still send you to the [NNDC databases](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/databases/databases.html), just a different one than you’ve found so far.  Probably you want [EXFOR](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/), which contains reaction data.  So if you wanted to search for the D-T fusion process,

$$
\rm
^3H(^2H,n)^4He
$$

you could put `H-3` as the target and `d,*` as the reaction for a list of all the things that deuterons can do on tritium.  For fusion among heavier nuclei, there is a list of “ion-induced reactions” which have data available.

Comment: Wow, this is super helpful!  I'll have to narrow down my scope a lot and learn how to effectively parse all the information they've got there, but that's exactly what I was looking for!